# SWI Prolog: avoiding name clashes between builtin predicates and dynamic predicates

Tags: module, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm wondering if it is possible to define a dynamic predicate with the same name and arity as a builtin predicate inside a module. I was hoping it would be enough to hide the builtin predicates in my module using [`delete_import_module/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=importmodule#delete_import_module/2). Alas, that doesn't seem to work. For instance, I cannot create a clause for `halt/1` inside module `foo`:

```
?- delete_import_module(foo, user).
true.

?- asserta(foo:halt(x)).
ERROR: No permission to modify static procedure `halt/1'
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] assert(foo:halt(x))
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:user: ...) at /usr/lib64/swipl-8.4.1/boot/toplevel.pl:1117
```

It still seems to think I'm talking about `system:halt/1` even though that's not even visible in `foo`. Why is that?

Comment: I think you can solve the problem by using the predicate redefine_system_predicate/1.

Comment: Hey @slago, that's an interesting suggestion, thank you. However what I'm really after is gaining a better understanding of the SWI Prolog module system. I thought that I can define whatever I want in my own module and it's not going to clash with what somebody else has defined in their module. But that doesn't seem to be the case here (at least for builtin predicates) and I'd like to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the problem goes away if I try to call the predicate before adding the clause:

```
?- delete_import_module(foo, user).
true.

?- foo:halt(_).
Correct to: "system:halt(_)"? no
ERROR: Unknown procedure: foo:halt/1
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         halt/0
ERROR: 
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] foo:halt(_20078)
ERROR:    [9] toplevel_call(user:foo: ...) at /usr/lib64/swipl-8.4.1/boot/toplevel.pl:1117
   Exception: (10) foo:halt(_8960) ? no debug
?- assert(foo:halt(_)).
true.

?- @(listing, foo).

:- dynamic halt/1.

halt(_).
true.
```

I've also tried poking the predicate in other ways (using `current_predicate/1` and `clause/2`), but that doesn't have the same effect.

So while this does solve the problem, I still wonder what is going on here. Is this a bug? I'm using SWI Prolog 8.4.1 on Fedora Linux.